# C - gcc: no compiler warning with different function-declaration/implementation

Tags: c, gcc, declaration

I try to figure out why my c-compiler gives me no warning/error with following (simplified) code.

The function-declaration have no parameters while the function-implementation have parameters:

**some.h:**

`void foo();`

**some.c:**

```
static uint32_t count = 0; 

void foo(uint32_t num) {
    count += num;
    print("Count: %u");
}
```

**main.c:**

```
foo(100);
foo();
```

**Output:**

```
Count: 100
Count: 100
```

**Compiler for target build:**

```
gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q1-20150306-win32
```

**Linker for target build:**

```
gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q1-20150306-win32
```

**Compiler-Flags:**

`-Wall -Werror -DuECC_CURVE=uECC_secp256r1 -DMEMORY_CHECK -DDEBUG -Os -g3 -DBACKTRACE`

Comment: your compilation statement? includes?

Comment: I suppose `print` is `printf`. BTW [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) is [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Please note that this is yet another case where C and C++ are very different. C++ programmers going over to C tend to make the mistake of writing `()` instead of `(void)`.

Answer (score 5):

Because of backward compatibility, a declaration like

```
void foo();
```

doesn't declare a function that takes no argument, it declares a function which takes an unknown number of arguments of unknown type.

That means both your calls are correct, and the compiler can't really warn you about it.

The other problematic thing is that the declaration in the source file actually matches the declaration in the header file, it just makes it more precise. Therefore you will not get a warning or error there either.

Comment: here is a declaration of a function that takes no argument: `void foo(void);`

Answer (score 0):

In C this function declaration

```
void foo();
```

means that there is nothing known about the function parameters in the point of the declaration.

The types and number of the parameters are deduced from a function call.

As for your program then this call

```
foo();
```

has undefined behavior because the number of parameters and the number of arguments mismatch.